# Link a file to CEWP that lives in another site collection

Tags: sharepoint-server, cewp, cross-site

I'm creating a Page that contains a CEWP which will link to an HTML file.

The plan is to template that site/page and use it across multiple sites and collections.

I want to link the HTML from 1 location so if we need to make an update across all sites, it can be done from said 1 location.

However, there's a new site collection created after a certain threshold so the link can't be in that path. For example:

```
mysite.com/projects/1/pro-1
mysite.com/projects/1/pro-2
mysite.com/projects/2/pro-3
mysite.com/projects/2/pro-4
mysite.com/projects/n/pro-5
mysite.com/projects/n/pro-n
```

Given this structure, the HTML file that the CEWP link to cannot be on /projects/1-n

I want to create something like `mysites.com/cdn/home/SiteAssets/custom.html` and use that link across all those sites above to link to the CEWP and make changes in one place.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SharePoint has the ability to a create a `ContentTypeHub`

The name is totally wrong, as it can do much more than just manage ContentTypes centrally

Basically it is a Site Collection where all users have access to

**and you can store any files you want in a Document Library on that ContentTypeHub**

So you can use it as your Company CDN (Content Delivery Network)

http://sharepointpals.com/post/An-introduction-to-Content-Type-Hub-in-SharePoint-Office-365

---

If you mean your filenames are changing, an option might to to load your JS file dynamically with:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6074833/load-and-execute-javascript-code-synchronously

Comment: The file names aren't changing. The issue is that the CEWP does not allow (by default) to link to a file outside of the Site Collection. So creating a content type hub is a good idea as a central location for code distribution but I don't think it would fix the issue with CEWP

Comment: Then have a simple CEWP script (like in the second link) that loads you main script

Comment: oh okay, what I could do is export the webpart and add in that script that loads my .js file from the repository. I'll give that a shot. Thx